# Methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, methods

So I made a JavaScript Object, which makes an  element in the DOM, and what I use my methods for, is to for example play the audio, set the duration of the audio etc. However, a method that I made inside my object apparently doesn't exist. By the way, I'm new, so I don't really know what I did wrong... But here is my code:

```
function Audio(paramSource) {
    var object = document.createElement("audio");
    (...)
    function play() {
        object.play();
    };
    (...)
};

var myAudio = new Audio("http://tufda.net/space/limewire.mp3");
myAudio.play();
```

Thanks in advance :)!

Comment: What method specifically doesn't exist? FYI: the `new Audio` method surely already [exists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement), and you shouldn't be overwriting it

Comment: @adeneo I was curious about the Audio.play() method, I should have probably pointed that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, you need to assign it as a property to the object.  Something like this:

```
function Audio(paramSource) {
    var object = document.createElement("audio");
    //...
    this.play = function() {
        object.play();
    };
    //...
};
```

A function can be declared like a variable, and for the `Audio` object to publicly expose it (instead of just being inside its own scope) you would simply set that variable to a property on `this` within that scope.

So in the above code, `object` is a variable internal to the scope of `Audio` and `play` is a property *on* `Audio`.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign to the object the `object` var:

```
function Audio(paramSource) {
    this.object = document.createElement("audio");
    (...)
    this.play = function() {
        this.object.play();
    };
    (...)
};

var myAudio = new Audio("http://tufda.net/space/limewire.mp3");
myAudio.play();
```

By this way you can access to `Audio.object` from outside.